# InterstageBPM : assign task to subset of role

Tags: interstage

How in Interstage BPM are we able to assign an activity to a subset of the Role to which it has been assigned?

For example, I have an activity DOSOMETHING which is assigned to GROUP X.
GROUP X is composed of users A, B, C, D and E.

If we need to assign the task (based on the value of an UDA) to a subset composed of users D and E, how can I proceed without having to duplicate the activity and adding a conditional node in the process definition to route the flow to the duplicated activity used to target the subset group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what the Role Actions are for. You will want to use the

1. Go to the **Activity Properties**.
2. Click on **Regular Actions** and select the **Role Action Set**.
3. Add the action: **Assign Task to User** in the **Workload Balancing Actions** folder.

   You can then do a few things. You can hard code a comma separated list of users. Or, get the list of users from a UDA. Or, if you want to get the subset of users from another Role you can use the **Get Role Members** action from the **Directory Actions**. Pass it the Role name and then put the return value in a UDA and pass that UDA to the **Assign Task to User** action.